# Virtual machines networking not working

Tags: linux, redhat, linux-networking, bmc

My [BMC](https://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/baseboard-management-controller) had *virtualization* disabled when I installed RHEL6.9. Does that mean the OS installation has dropped all the virtualization packages like libguestfs, etc? if so then what is the best solution to get them?:

1. enable Virtualization in bios and then reinstall the OS
2. enable Virtualization in bios and then using a package manager install the necessary files required for VMs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether your operating system has various software installed has no relation to your BIOS settings. You configure these separately. Of course there is no need to reinstall the operating system; you can simply install the packages you want But RHEL 6.9 is old; you should probably use a more current RHEL distribution.

Comment: the migration from 6.9 to 7 is in progress!